# Arranging only a subset of the graph nodes in a particular layout using cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, arbor.js, cytoscape.js

Cytoscape JS offers an interesting feature called **LAYOUTS.**
I want to arrange a collection of nodes in a circular layout.
But **I do not want all the nodes of my network graph to lie on that circle.**

How can I do this using cytoscape.js?

Additional Explanation (optional)-

Here is an example I built using Arbor JS, which I am considering re-implementing using Cytoscape in a fixed manner, showing all nodes at once.- [Cluster-Mapping](http://webfuel.co.in/pranjal/cluster-mapping/)

I want just the Nodes (orange dots) to be represented on a circle and NOT the Instances (brown rectangles) that appear on hovering in this arbor based example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a planned feature.  I created a ticket for you to track its progress. https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/295

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible with `eles.layout()` (version 3.7).

Refer to the documentation: [eles.layout()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.layout)